# Gnuplot crashed unexpectedly - ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: 18.04, segmentation-fault, gnuplot

I've been having an issue with `gnuplot` (Version 5.2 patchlevel 2) on ubuntu 18.04.
When trying to zoom using the right click button, the window goes away.

I removed and reinstalled it but this didn't fix the issue.

My `journal` entries when it crashes are the following

```
Aug 17 12:20:23 xxx kernel: gnuplot[33387]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000000000 sp 00007ffc90bb04f8 error 14
Aug 17 12:20:14 xxx kernel: gnuplot[32982]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000000000 sp 00007fffa979b928 error 14
Aug 17 12:20:09 xxx kernel: gnuplot[32805]: segfault at 14fb48131230 ip 000014fb48131230 sp 00007ffe7e9b6848 error 15
Aug 17 12:20:04 xxx kernel: gnuplot[32171]: segfault at 363634342e2e ip 0000145b961d5988 sp 0000145b8a6d3898 error 4 in libpango-1.0.so.0.4000.14[145b961c4000+4a000]
Aug 17 12:19:14 xxx kernel: gnuplot[28996]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000000000 sp 00007ffe1f8cf698 error 14
Aug 17 12:15:17 xxx kernel: traps: gnuplot[17056] general protection ip:15074ba65ac5 sp:15073f43a830 error:0 in libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0.4.0[15074b814000+5b1000]
```

I'm not great at interpreting segfault errors so any help on that is more than welcome!

Also when plotting, before the canvas pops up I get the following on the terminal:

```
** (gnuplot:20785): WARNING **: 16:30:33.030: Unable to connect to dbus: The given address is empty    
(gnuplot:20785): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:30:33.037: g_dbus_connection_register_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed    
(gnuplot:20785): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:30:33.038: g_dbus_connection_register_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed    
(gnuplot:20785): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:30:33.038: g_dbus_connection_get_unique_name: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed    
(gnuplot:20785): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:30:33.076: g_dbus_connection_register_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed    
(gnuplot:20785): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:30:33.076: g_dbus_connection_register_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
(gnuplot:20785): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:30:33.076: g_dbus_connection_get_unique_name: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed    
(gnuplot:20785): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:30:33.097: g_dbus_connection_register_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed    
(gnuplot:20785): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:30:33.097: g_dbus_connection_register_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed    
(gnuplot:20785): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:30:33.097: g_dbus_connection_get_unique_name: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
gnuplot> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Also a few useful outputs

```
$ apt-cache policy gnuplot
gnuplot:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.2.2+dfsg1-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     5.2.2+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages

$ which gnuplot
/usr/bin/gnuplot

$ ldd $(which gnuplot)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffff5caf000)
    libedit.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.so.2 (0x000014e29001b000)
    libgd.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgd.so.3 (0x000014e28fdb4000)
    liblua5.3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.3.so.0 (0x000014e28fb7d000)
    libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0 (0x000014e28f34b000)
    libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0 (0x000014e28eebc000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x000014e28ecaf000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x000014e28ea62000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x000014e28e80e000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x000014e28e4f7000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x000014e28e1da000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x000014e28dea2000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x000014e28dc9e000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x000014e28d915000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x000014e28d577000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000014e28d35f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x000014e28d140000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x000014e28cd4f000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x000014e28cb25000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x000014e28c8f3000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x000014e28c6d6000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x000014e28c491000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x000014e28c1dd000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x000014e28bf75000)
    libXpm.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4 (0x000014e28bd63000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x000014e28baec000)
    libwebp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x000014e28b883000)
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x000014e28b241000)
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x000014e28af8c000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x000014e28ad68000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x000014e28ab62000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x000014e28a95a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000014e290629000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x000014e28a744000)
    libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x000014e28a53b000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x000014e28a333000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x000014e28a0c1000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x000014e289e1c000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x000014e289c19000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x000014e2899f1000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x000014e2897e4000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x000014e2895da000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x000014e2893c8000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x000014e2891c0000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x000014e288f8e000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x000014e288d68000)
    libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x000014e288b5a000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x000014e288956000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x000014e288750000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x000014e28852a000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x000014e28818b000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x000014e287f88000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x000014e287d78000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x000014e287b6d000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x000014e287963000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x000014e287760000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x000014e28755d000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x000014e287342000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x000014e28713b000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x000014e286e9d000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x000014e286c96000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x000014e286a92000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x000014e28688c000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x000014e286664000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x000014e28644a000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x000014e2861f6000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x000014e285fe1000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x000014e285db4000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x000014e285b67000)
```

Info about video:

```
$ lsmod | grep drm
nvidia_drm             57344  9
nvidia_modeset       1191936  14 nvidia_drm
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   401408  13 drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nvidia_drm
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

$ lspci -k | grep -Ei "VGA|3d|video|graphic" -A3
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
03:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 3753
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)



 $ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_0
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.1 (libva 2.1.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Splitted-Desktop Systems VDPAU backend for VA-API - 0.7.4
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG4Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG4AdvancedSimple    : VAEntrypointVLD
      <unknown profile>               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

Comment: To be sure if it's not a dependencies issue or a bug in the version you are using, could you try to use a very simple example and check if this still returns error?

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy gnuplot`; `which gnuplot` and `ldd $(which gnuplot)` to the question.

Comment: @Unix: essentially this happens when I interactively communicating with the GUI i.e. using the mouse and more specifically only when zooming.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks for your reply. I've updated my question.

Comment: Please add the output of `lsmod | grep drm`, `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`, `lspci -k | grep -Ei "VGA|3d|video|graphic" -A3` , `sudo apt-get install vainfo`, `vainfo`.

Comment: @N0rbert: Thanks a lot for your time! I updated my question with more info!

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install vdpau-va-driver` to fix error in `vainfo`, then reboot and run `vainfo` with gnuplot again.

Comment: @N0rbert: Thanks a lot! Question was updated!

Comment: Do you still have GNU Plot crash?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to reinstall GNUPlot and libraries from official repositories by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnuplot libwxgtk3.0-0v5 libpango-1.0-0
```

and check its functionality.

To fix the possible problem with video drivers install `vainfo` by `sudo apt-get install vainfo` and then check its output. To get video acceleration for Nvidia install the following package which provides [`nvidia_drv_video.so`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=nvidia_drv_video.so) library by:

```
sudo apt-get install vdpau-va-driver
```

reboot and retry to launch GNU Plot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just did and I get the same behavior.

Comment: Try to reinstall with libraries.

Comment: Exactly the same thing. I don't know how to provide more info on that.

Comment: It maybe video driver issue. Can't reproduce on Intel and fully upgraded Ubuntu MATE 18.04.5 LTS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I check if it's a video driver issue? Also check my question on updated infor

Comment: I already had `vdpau-va-driver` installed and gnuplot is still crashing. The tough part is to identify the reason it's crashing and I thought that the `journal` would help